# QTreeWidget custom selection and hover background colors behavior

Tags: css, linux, windows, pyqt, qt5

I need to set to none a highlight color of hover and selected item in QTreeWidget. But also I want selected or highlighted items to be with some sort of border.

Now I have my QTreeWidget like this:

[image]

Item "model_1" has green background color like "model_2". When I select or just hover it becomes blue and I can not see an original background color. I want to see original background color (in this example it is green).

I've tried to do it with [stylesheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html):

```
QTreeView::item:selected {
    border: black;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,128,255,100);
}

QTreeView::item:hover {
    border: black;
    border-radius:1px;
    background-color: rgba(0,128,255,95);

}

QTreeView::item:hover:selected {
    border: black;
    border-radius:1px;
    background-color: rgba(0,128,255,70);

}
```

I tried to set `background-color: inherit;` but it does not work...

As I saw [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#color):

> Note: The RGB colors allowed are the same as those allowed with CSS 2.1, as listed [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units).

some keywords like "inherit" are not supported..

I need to do it on Linux and Windows.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

1. Add stylesheet to your application for activating selection and hovering

> ```
> self.setStyleSheet("""
>     QTreeView::item:selected {
>     }
>
>     QTreeView::item:hover {
>     }
>
>     QTreeView::item:hover:selected {
>     }
> """)
> ```

2. Create following class for custom style delegate for items.

> ```
> class MyStyledItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
>         '''
>             For overriding behavior of selection and hovering in QTreeView and QTreeWidget
>
>             When you set background color (QtGui.QColor()) to QTreeWidgetItem you also must set this color like: 
>                 item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, QtGui.QColor())
>         '''
>         def paint(self, painter, option, index):
>             def draw_my(option, painter, brush, text, icon):
>                 if brush is None:
>                     brush = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 0) # This is original background color. I just set alpha to 0 which means it is transparent
>
>                 x, y = (option.rect.x(), option.rect.y())
>                 h = option.rect.height()
>                 painter.save()
>
>                 painter.setFont(option.font)
>                 if icon:
>                     icon = icon.pixmap(h, h)
>                     painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QRect(x, y, h, h), icon)
>                     painter.drawText(option.rect.adjusted(h, 0, 0, 0), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, text)
>                 else:
>                     painter.drawText(option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, text)
>
>                 painter.setCompositionMode(QtGui.QPainter.CompositionMode_SourceAtop)
>                 painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
>                 painter.fillRect(option.rect, brush)
>                 painter.setBackgroundMode(QtCore.Qt.OpaqueMode)
>                 painter.setBackground(brush)
>                 painter.drawRect(option.rect)
>                 painter.restore()
>
>             # Also should be activated in StyleSheet
>             #                             Selected                                             Hovered
>             if (option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected) or (option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_MouseOver):
>                 option.font.setWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
>
>                 brush = index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
>                 text = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
>                 icon = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
>
>                 draw_my(option=option, painter=painter, brush=brush, text=text, icon=icon)   
>             else:
>                 QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
> ```

3. Set your custom delegate to `QTreeWidget` object

> custom_QStyledItemDelegate = MyStyledItemDelegate()
>   tree_widget.setItemDelegate(custom_QStyledItemDelegate)

4. When you set background color for item, also set data like following

> item.setBackground(0, QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 150, 100)))
>
> item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole, QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 150,
>   100)) # Need for paint selected and hoovered data in MyStyledItemDelegate

5. Enjoy

[image]

PS: I'm sorry for such bad style of this answer, I could not understand how to set code style for my code snippets.. It did not work.